# Keep getting error "Undefined function 'Convert' in expression" in Access

Tags: sql, date-difference

I am trying to calculate the difference between the Maxtime and Mintime however, I think the issue is with converting the 'timestamp' to a date that I can take the difference of. Any help in creating a column that takes the difference of days between these two columns would be so helpful! Thanks!!!

```
SELECT user, 
   Min(convert(timestamp,"%m/%d/%Y")) as Mintime,     
   Max(convert(timestamp,"%m/%d/%Y")) as Maxtime, 
  ( Min(timestamp)-Max(timestamp)) AS Expr1
  FROM table1
  GROUP BY user
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no convert function in Access. So you are getting the error.

If you want to convert timestamp to a date you can use the datevalue function in Access.